# add dashed between 2 strings to generate equal length lines

Tags: javascript

I have an array of people

```
const family = [{name: 'Mike', age: 1}, {name: 'Monique', age: 99}]
family.map(member => ??)
```

the desired output is

```
Mike ......... 1
Monique ..... 99
```

the number of . is different betwen line 1 an 2. can you help me think about this? thanks!

Comment: What if another line?

Comment: what will be the maximum length of the name

Comment: Spec is unclear. What's the logic for determining the number of `.`s? Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: that´s exactly the question... I just need to align numbers to the right and fille the gap with ...

Comment: @handsome see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61335401/2813224)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const maxLength = 100;
family.map(member => {
    let line = new Array(maxLength - (member.name + member.age).length).fill('.');
    console.log(member.name + line.join('') + member.age);
})
```

goodluck

Answer (score 0):

1. @params: objArray [Array of Objects]
                     lineSize [Number] length of each output line
2. `.map()` each Object

   - get the length of name value
   - get the length of score after its converted to String
   - subtract the total of both lengths and two spaces from the given `lineSize`
   - fill an Array of dots equal to the difference from previous step and then `.join('')` them into a String.
   - return each line as: `obj.name .... obj.score` into an Array
3. Create a [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) and a `<ul>` and ensure that a [monospaced font](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_monospaced_typefaces) is applied to `<ul>`. Monospaced fonts will make the list perfectly even.
4. `.forEach()` String of the previous Array:

   - create a `<li>`
   - add a line to `<li>`
   - append `<li>` to `<ul>`
5. Append `<ul>` to documentFragment then the documentFragment to `<body>`

---

#### Demo

```js
const scores = [{
  name: 'Mike',
  score: 1
}, {
  name: 'Monique',
  score: 99
}, {
  name: 'Matt',
  score: 5150
}, {
  name: 'Lynda',
  score: 2112
}];
/* Step 1 */
const memberList = (objArray, lineSize) => {
  /* Step 2 */
  let scoreArray = objArray.map(obj => {
    let nameSize = obj['name'].length;
    let scoreSize = obj['score'].toString().length;
    let subTotal = lineSize - (nameSize + scoreSize);
    let delimiters = ` ${Array(subTotal).fill('.').join('')} `;
    return `${obj.name}${delimiters}${obj.score}`;
  });
  /* Step 3 */
  const docFrag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  const list = document.createElement('ul');
  list.style.cssText = `font: 400 3vw/1.5 Consolas;list-style: none;`
  /* Step 4 */
  scoreArray.forEach(line => {
    const item = document.createElement('li');
    item.textContent = line;
    list.appendChild(item);
  });
  /* Step 5 */
  docFrag.appendChild(list);
  document.body.appendChild(docFrag);
}

memberList(scores, 20);
```

Answer (score 0):

based on @tdjprog approach I wrote this

```
const separateWords = (string1, string2, length = 40) => {
    const times = length - (string1 + string2).length;
    return string1 + " " + ".".repeat(times) + " " + string2;
};
```

hope it helps someone. cheers